# Delay in updating D3 map in react

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have a map of London boroughs using D3 in a react app, and want the user to be able to select one. I have it set to change colour to light red when hovering over a borough, which works fine. When the user clicks a borough, it "selects" it. This, however, takes half a second to update the colour on the map and stops. I can't seem to figure out why this happens, any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { geoMercator, geoPath } from 'd3-geo';
import { select } from 'd3-selection';
import geojson from './london_boroughs.json';

class BoroughMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            width: 960,
            height: 680,
            borough: null,
            prev: null,
            selected: false,
            boroughList: []
        };
    };

    onClick = (e, d) => {
        if ((this.state.selected === true) && (d.properties.name === this.state.borough)) {
            select(e.target).attr('fill', '#eee');
            select('#label').text("Please select a borough");
            this.setState({
                prev: null,
                borough: null,
                selected: false
            });
        } else {
            select(this.state.prev).attr('fill', '#eee');
            select('#label').text(d.properties.name);
            select(e.target).attr('fill', 'red');
            this.setState({
                selected: true,
                borough: d.properties.name,
                prev: e.target
            });
        }
    }

    onMouseOut = (e, d) => {
        if (this.state.selected === false) {
            select('#label').text("Please select a borough");
        } else {
            select('#label').text(this.state.borough);
        }
        if (d.properties.name !== this.state.borough) {
            select(e.target).attr('fill', '#eee');
        }
    }

    onMouseEnter = (e, d) => {
        select('#label').text(d.properties.name);
        if (d.properties.name !== this.state.borough) {
            select(e.target).attr('fill', '#ff7f7f');
        }
    }

    render() {
        const path = geoPath().projection(geoMercator().fitExtent([[0, 0], [this.state.width, this.state.height * 0.9]], geojson));
        return (
            <div>
                <svg width={this.state.width} height={this.state.height}>
                    <g>
                        {geojson.features.map(d => (
                            <path
                                key={d.properties.name}
                                d={path(d)}
                                fill="#eee"
                                stroke="#0e1724"
                                strokeWidth="2"
                                strokeOpacity="0.5"
                                onMouseEnter={e => this.onMouseEnter(e, d)}
                                onMouseOut={e => this.onMouseOut(e, d)}
                                onClick={e => { this.onClick(e, d) }}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </g>
                </svg>
                <br style={{ padding: "1%" }} />
                <h1 id="label">Please select a borough</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(BoroughMap);
```

Comment: How many `features` are there in `geojson` ?

Comment: @Pandaiolo there are 32, one for each borough.

Comment: It feels like `path(d)` is taking something like 15ms, which accounts to 500ms for the 32 borough? I think you should change the logic to build the svg paths once for a given width/height (in an `useMemo`), and only change the relevant svg styles properties with the right color, if only that changes, to avoid recompute the path every time. I'll leave it to someone better at d3/svg than me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, better not to store node in state, can be a new node on every click.

```
   // select(this.state.prev).attr('fill', '#eee');
   select(e.target).attr('fill', '#eee');
    select('#label').text(d.properties.name);
    select(e.target).attr('fill', 'red');
    this.setState({
        selected: true,
        borough: d.properties.name,
        // prev: e.target
    });
```

Also in every **setState** whole D3 stuff get re-rendered a new. As other commenter noted **path** can be heavy, it recalculates on every render.

Can try to move D3 part to separate component, use *memo* and *useCallback* in parent component.

D3 and React not so easy to get work together, maybe consider use [visx](https://airbnb.io/visx/)

Comment: I moved the `borough`, `prev` and `selected` variables out of the state, which did the trick.